# Observable updating values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, observable

My problem is simple 
I want every time the user selects a package the valid_until column increments based on the selected package;
To solve this I created a

```
 PackageObservable{
    public function creating(Package $package)
        {    DB::table('permit')
        ->select('permit.valid_until')
        ->join('package', 'user_id', '=', 'package.user_id')
        ->where('package.name','=',$package->name)
         ->addMonths(12);
        DB::table('permit')
            ->select('permit.name')
            ->join('package', 'user_id', '=', 'package.user_id')
            ->where('package.name','=','option3')
            ->addWeeks(1);
 }}
```

The problem is I dont know how to get the package.name.
The relationships between Package and Permit are these:

1. Package(id,name,entry_nr,user_id,price,flga_six_days)
2. Permit(id,user_id,membership_id,used_entries,valid_until,entries,flag_six_days)
   Thanks in advance!I appreciate your help!
   throws :

> BadMethodCallException Method  addMonths does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have something like the following in your ServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    Package::observe(PackageObservable::class);
}
```

The package model should be passed to the Observable class so to get the package name you should simply be able to do `$package->name`. If this is null then when you're creating the package you're not defining the name.

All the following command does is tries to run a select statement;

```
DB::table('permit')
        ->select('permit.valid_until')
        ->join('package', 'user_id', '=', 'package.user_id')
        ->where('package.name','=',$package->name)
         ->addMonths(12);
```

The method `addMonths` does not exist on the query builder. Do you have an `addMonths()` method on your permit model?

You probably want to do something along the lines of

```
 $permit = Permit::select("valid_until")->where('user_id',$package->user_id)->orderBy('user_id', 'desc')->first(); 

 if ($permit) {
     $newValidUntil = $permit->valid_until->addMonths(12);
     $permit->update(['valid_until' => $newValidUntil]);
 }
```

If you comment to let me know how you get on I can always update my answer to suit any extra info you need.

Comment: $date=Permit::select("valid_until")
        ->where('user_id',$package->user_id)
        ->orderBy('user_id', 'desc')->first();


       $new =$date->valid_until->addMonths(12);
            dd($new);

       $new2 = $date->save();
I already did this just tell me how to save it

Comment: somehow the value isn't being saved in the db,just take my answer and edit yours but tell me how to save it

Comment: $date->update(['valid_until' => $new]); If you have a 'fillable' property on the model you'll need to make sure valid_until is in that array.

Comment: still not updated even though when I dd($date) the date is changed don't know where the prb is

Comment: Do you have a fillable property on your model?

Comment: yes,`code protected $fillable = [
  'user_id',
  'membership_id',
  'used_entries',
  'valid_until',
  'entries',
  'flag_six_days'
 ];`

Comment: What happens if you dd `$permit->update([valid_until => $newValidUntil]);` or your code equivilant?

Comment: I think its eq but let me try

Comment: true returned true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168342/discussion-between-simon-r-and-james-moore).